# How do I control the order of this multidimensional array, based on a particular value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, asort

After reading several posts here about this subject, I am unable to find the exact answer to my problem.

My current array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Level] => Bronze
            [Name] => JP Morgan
            [Logo] => Logo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Level] => Bronze
            [Name] => NASDAQ OMX
            [Logo] => Logo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Level] => Platinum
            [Name] => Credit Suisse
            [Logo] => Logo
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Level] => Silver
            [Name] => BNP Paribas
            [Logo] => Logo
        )

)
```

What I want is to have all sponsors sorted by `[Level]` of which the order is:

- Platinum
- Gold
- Silver
- Bronze

How do I do this?

Comment: where is gold (o_O) ?

Comment: LOL, that is not in the array yet, but will be. This is just an example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your [own sorting function](https://php.net//manual/en/function.usort.php). For example, you'd specify your own custom order that you want it to follow:

```
$sort_order = array('Platinum', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze');
```

Pass your array with all your data into your custom sort function, and search for the value's key position (in this case, `Level`) in the sort order you've just defined:

```
$array = array(
  array (
    'Level' => 'Bronze',
      'Name' => 'JP Morgan',
      'Logo' => 'Logo'
  ),
  array (
      'Level' => 'Bronze',
      'Name' => 'NASDAQ OMX',
      'Logo' => 'Logo'
  ),
  array (
      'Level' => 'Platinum',
      'Name' => 'Credit Suisse',
      'Logo' => 'Logo'
  ),
  array (
      'Level' => 'Silver',
      'Name' => 'BNP Paribas',
      'Logo' => 'Logo'
  ),
);

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($sort_order) {
    return array_search($a['Level'], $sort_order) - array_search($b['Level'], $sort_order);
});

print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Level] => Platinum
        [Name] => Credit Suisse
        [Logo] => Logo
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Level] => Silver
        [Name] => BNP Paribas
        [Logo] => Logo
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Level] => Bronze
        [Name] => NASDAQ OMX
        [Logo] => Logo
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Level] => Bronze
        [Name] => Jp Morgan
        [Logo] => Logo
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is excellent. Learnt again and it works perfectly :)